# How to get sample rows from a view in Sybase IQ

Tags: random, sybase, sap-iq

I am trying to get a sample data from a `view` in Sybase IQ 16.

To get sample data from a `table` I used the below query and it works fine for a `table`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE RAND(ROWID(table1)) < .05;
```

However, when trying to get data from a `view`< i am getting below error.

```
SQL Anywhere Error -1113: Correlation name 'view_name' is not valid for use with the ROWID function
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an IQ engine if front of me right now, but this should push you in the right direction

```
with cte (
  select a.*, rand() as rnd from view1 a
) 
select top 10
from cte
order by rnd
```